# redirect to another page in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hello guys am new to react native and am trying to make a redirect of the page that only happens when someone presses on the image on the current page. The press event is on the touchableopacity  ,I want when the redirect is made the data displayed on that page you have been redirected to should come from the id of the image someone pressed on in the previous page

I have tried to use navigation.navigate prop in the component but it only redirect but does not record the id pressed so no data is showing

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate using

```
navigation.navigate('YourScreen', { itemId: 'some_id', otherParam: 'anything you want here'});
```

Then in your next screen that you navigated to

```
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { itemId, otherParam } = route.params; <- Grab params here
  console.log(itemId);
  return (
    <SomeComponent />
  );
}
```

You can see in the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)